# Xen Domain0 Has Network But DomainU does not

Tags: ubuntu, networking, xen, bridge, netplan

After re-installing my domain 0, a guest VM (domain U) is no longer able to connect to the network.

I am using Ubuntu 20.4 on my Domain 0 with Xen 4.11. I am able to successfully connect to internet on this.

**cat /etc/netplan/config.yaml**

```
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd

  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  bridges:
    xenbr0:
      interfaces: [enp0s25]
      addresses: [192.168.1.99/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

**#ip route list**:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev xenbr0 proto static 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

from .cfg file for Domain U:

```
vif         = [ 'ip=192.168.1.102 ,mac=00:16:3E:75:C2:D9,bridge=xenbr0' ]
```

In Domain U:
**$ping 8.8.8.8**

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 253ms
```

I'm kind of stumped, this Domain U was previously able to connect to the network before I had to re-install this domain 0. What steps or troubleshooting do you recommend to get this to connect?

Possible clues: the domain U was previously on a different physical hypervisor, so in addition to a new domain 0 it's a new NIC.
A freshly installed domain U using xen-create-image is also not able to connect.
This leads me to conclude the issue is with my setup with domain 0.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

I was able to resolve this by re-installing domain0.
The only setting I changed vs the domain0 that was getting the error was this time I did not include docker in the installed packages list.

For some context about why I had two different kinds of virtualization: I am transitioning to containers, but still have some services in VMs. I wanted to be able to keep my old services active while transitioning. The workaround I'm choosing is to create a new VM, and install docker on that.

I can only conclude that the docker bridge was in someway interfering with the bridge I had set for the VMs. Perhaps docker is not compatible with xen hypervisor? If anyone has further context about this I'm very curious.